# Is there a CSS or Jquery term for side bar menu on a page with panel content on the righthandside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to build something like this into my webpage:

I'm interested in the box at the bottom of my mockup, which shows the menu items on the lhs and the panel on the rhs that will show different content when clicked. I'd like to build it in html and jquery if possible.

I've seem similar things before, but I don't know the term for them. At the moment I'm googling show/hide panels show/hide menu buttons etc, but nothing is coming up. So hoping that this is a standard (ish) thing and that someone can help me out and let me know what I should be Googling!!!

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Maybe this https://codepen.io/shakdaniel/pen/qdWaJq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a "tab panel" (or "tabbed panel"), with the tabs arranged vertically on the left. This is usually an option available on various tab panels even if they default to tabs across the top.